# Screen: Current directory in caption bar (not as title)

Tags: zsh, gnu-screen, oh-my-zsh

How can I show the current directory of the currently active session in a screen status bar (not as title of the session!)?

I have tried with various combinations n,m={0,1} of

```
backtick 102 n m pwd
caption string '%102`'
```

(Shell is zsh with oh-my-zsh)

Answer (score 3):

I think you will find much interest in [this](http://zshwiki.org/home/examples/hardstatus). Seems like what is done is set a title with a small function in `zsh` to the current directory then run this before every command then trap that in `screen`... I don't think using hardstatus or caption makes a difference to the method:

in .`zshrc`:

```
function title {
  if [[ $TERM == "screen" ]]; then
    # Use these two for GNU Screen:
    print -nR $'\033k'$1$'\033'\\

    print -nR $'\033]0;'$2$'\a'
  elif [[ $TERM == "xterm" || $TERM == "rxvt" ]]; then
    # Use this one instead for XTerms:
    print -nR $'\033]0;'$*$'\a'
  fi
}

function precmd {
  title zsh "$PWD"
}

function preexec {
  emulate -L zsh
  local -a cmd; cmd=(${(z)1})
  title $cmd[1]:t "$cmd[2,-1]"
}
```

In `.screenrc`:

```
caption always "%3n %t%? (%u)%?%?: %h%?"
```

[image]

Comment: This does not work for me. If i just start, it 
sets the window's title to: "%15<..<%~%<<"    if i run a program for instance "nano: %100>...>nano%<<". In any way I think this will not help me because I do want to be able to set the title *independantly* of displaying the current directory in the status/caption.

Comment: I don't understand as I had tested this before answering and I just tested it now. Works flawlessly on my side. I'm not a specialist; what I've found is that you cannot just add a command to the screen caption or status. On another multiplexer I could run `uptime` piped to `cut` in the status etc. Everyone I've seen accomplish what you wanted did it using the function and precmd in .zshrc - this setup is all over the web. Maybe someone with more expertise will bring an answer which can satisfy your constraint.

Comment: I'm thinking maybe you could use the solution but modify it to remove the title after it has been used i.e. clear it after it appears... maybe using something [here](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Functions.html) or modifying precmd in some way. If you end up doing something like that please contribute an answer. Thanks!

Comment: I will try to dig deeper into zsh, but that will probably take some time. I will keep this updated if I find something that works for me, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

I do this with bash. bash will trigger `PROMPT_COMMAND` every time the prompt comes up, so then you can echo the directory inside the escape codes.

In my `.screenrc`:

```
setenv PROMPT_COMMAND 'echo -ne "\033_`pwd`\033\\"'
caption string '%{+b}%n*%t%{-} %h%='
```

Comment: OP is using zsh, not bash